# How can I use a 'Get' statement to add to a variable list within a foreach loop?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use a 'Get' statement within a foreach loop to store the results within a variable list.
Below is an example code:

```
$runningServices = "Search Host Controller Service", "Managed Metadata Web Service", "Business Data Connectivity Service", "Secure Store Service"

foreach ($runningService in $runningServices)
{
    $derp += Get-SPServiceInstance | Where-Object {$_.TypeName -like $runningService -and $_.Server -like '*APP'} | Select TypeName, Server, Status
}

$derp
```

Currently this only shows the first entry and throws up an error that PSObject doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'.

Any help on how I store all 4 of the services in the variable and have it output would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either declare `$derp` as an array and use your code as it is or omit the add and just *assing the foreach statement* to `$derp`:

```
$derp = foreach ($runningService in $runningServices)
{
   Get-SPServiceInstance | Where-Object {$_.TypeName -like $runningService -and $_.Server -like '*APP'} | Select TypeName, Server, Status
}
```